# How to print a field value of an object when inline edit button is clicked in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to console log a particular attribute of an object when I click on edit button, is this possible using the below borrowed code?

Kindly advise on how to use the index to get value of "name". See the last line of the code with comment.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  enableEdit = false;
  enableEditIndex = null;
  wantedValue = '';
  backendData = [{
    "name": 'Target',
    "value": '100',
    "description": 'abc'
  },
  {
    "name": 'Size',
    "value": '20',
    "description": 'def'
  },
  {
    "name": 'Industry',
    "value": '40',
    "description": 'ghi'
  }]

  enableEditMethod(e, i) {
    this.enableEdit = true;
    this.enableEditIndex = i;
    console.log(i, e);

    this.wantedValue = //the selected name value
    console.log(// this.wantedValue //); //I want to get the name if the index (object) that is to be editted. e.g I 
    want "Industry" in console.
  }
}
```

Comment: How are your objects being displayed in the template?

Comment: In a table with the following order: name | value | description. And I want the editted index name in console.

Comment: You'll need to share the appropriate code in the template. 1. How are you editing each entry? 2. Are you iterating over the array 3. Once editing is done only do you want the value or while editing itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
in template

```
<div *ngFor="let e of backendData; let i = index">
....
  <button (click)="enableEditMethod(e, i)">Edit</button>
....
</div>
```

in .ts file

```
enableEditMethod(e, i) { 
    ..... Your Code .....
    console.log(e.name);
}
```